# Why am I getting a filenotfound exception even though my file is there in the correct location?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

The following code of mine used to work before. But after I've recently formatted my mobile, it doesn't work anymore. Please help me with this.

The code for setting the path is:

```
 path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/IMG-20190324-WA0000.jpg";
 try {
        m.addAttachment(path);

        if(m.send()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Email was sent successfully :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Email was not sent :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
E/MailApp: Could not send email
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/IMG-20190324-WA0000.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

My manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The file is at the exact location like before, then why can't the code read it?

[The file location screenshot :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e109d.jpg)

Comment: Note that the screen shot is for Internal Storage but you are requesting permission for External Storage.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you also GRANT the permission?

Comment: @PKlumpp how do I do that?

Comment: @Lubji you go to your device settings, to apps, choose your app and allow permissions. I assume that you do not request permissions from inside your app atm

Comment: @Pklumpp Love you bro ....it worked; much Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was go to Device settings -> apps -> my app -> switch on *storage* permission. Credit goes to @Pklumpp for helping me out

Comment: Glad i could help you, and btw, welcome to stackoverflow!